# $X_{n}$ and $Z$ be random variables if $X_{n} \ge Z$ then $ E[\liminf_{n\to \infty} X_{n}] \le \liminf_{n\to \infty} E[X_{n}] $

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable

Let $X_{n}$ and $Z$ be random variables on probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,P)$ and $Z$ be integrable. show that $$X_{n} \ge Z \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad E[\liminf_{n\to \infty}  X_{n}] \le \liminf_{n\to \infty}  E[X_{n}] $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to construct a sequence of non-negative random variables and then use [Fatou's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma). 2nd Hint: you need the integrability assumption to get rid of the terms containing $Z$.